# Can't update iframe content with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, iframe

**iframe** is loaded dynamically into container **div** inside function.

With **cc.text(content);** I try to update #code content.

I check changed text in runtime, it's updated but on screen value remains the same.

I am not a javascript pro, so any comments are welcome:

```
    function ShowEditor(content) {
        var url = "XmlEditor/Editor.htm";
        slHost.css('width', '0%');
        jobPlanContainer.css('display', 'block');
        frame = $('<iframe id="' + jobPlanIFrameID + '" src="' + url + '" class="frame" frameborder="0" />');
        frame.appendTo(jobPlanIFrameContainer);

        $(frame).load(function () {
            var ifr = frame[0];
            var doc = ifr.contentDocument || ifr.contentWindow.document;
            var jdoc = $(doc);
            var cc = jdoc.contents().find("#code");
            // var tst = cc.text();
            // alert(tst);
            cc.text(content);
        });
    }
```

I get the text in commented code, but fail to update #code content.

iframe holds the following html where I omit details inside **head** and **script**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head></head>
<body>
<form>
<textarea id="code" name="code">some texts</textarea>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see no problem. Are you sure your "content" is OK ? Did you try putting the alert after the `cc.text(content)` ? Can it be that the editor catches and revert the modification ?

Comment: The thing is when I check if text is changed with: frame.contents().find("#code").text(content); everything is ok, but onscreen value remains the same.

Comment: Yes, alert check gives correct value, but onscreen value remains the same

Comment: Post a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), to help diagnose problem faster

Comment: This must be a problem with the editor. It simply doesn't read more than once what's in the textarea. It probably offers a method to change the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML editor doesn't read more than once what's in the textarea.

A simple solution would be to generate in javascript the iframe content with the desired textarea content instead of loading it and then try to change the textarea content.

In fact (depending on the capacities of your XML Editor), you probably can do that directly in a generated text area instead of using a whole iframe to do it.

Comment: Looks like as a solution for me as well. I will try it and feedback later.